# @AspectJ aspects not being weaved in application that uses Spring

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aspects

I have added the line `<context:load-time-weaver/>`
to my application-context.xml,

and have created a `META-INF\aop.xml` file with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>

    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="com.xxx.aspectj.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.xxx.aspectj.StandardAspect"/>
    </aspects>

</aspectj>
```

With the aspect including a catch-all to simply see if it is even working:

```
@After("call (public * *(..))")
public void interceptEverything() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

But nothing seems to happen, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `include within` tag solved my problem.

I realized that I have misinterpreted the `include within` tag, I thought it had meant only weave aspects in the package listed, but it meant only weave aspects into classes in the package listed.